# Map tiles not loading until a zoom is executed

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The initial map is missing tile. No errors in the console. If I zoom though, the tiles refresh and all of them load. See attached screenshots.[image: Map on Load]

I have used //js.arcgis.com/3.18 API.

Please let me know how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your map element, make sure to specify a center and zoom property e.g.

```
var map = new Map("map-canvas", {
  basemap: "hybrid",
  center: [-120.33, 47.43],
  zoom: 15
});
```

Comment: I have initialized map element as you have suggested. Still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you at least get the most basic map to work?  Try with this sandbox link: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_simple

Comment: Basic map i made to work. And also i got to know where I'm facing the issue. I have used LoadFeatures function on map.Load. LoadFeature basically fetches all the mapped objects from FeatureService and plots on basic map. If i add this part of code,map tiles are not loading. Please help me how to handle this.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on Esri Geonet - your question will get more exposure there and users can look at your code samples in the comments section.